# Looping through a list of attirubutes from Django

Tags: python, django, oop, model

Basically, I've learned this far that coding something the right way means you shouldn't have to copy and paste a lot.. At least from what I've read.

I basically need to assign my Django model points based on a boolean statement. If True add points otherwise dont add points. The point values will change but for now I have them set as 1.

I can either copy/paste as many of these are I have to record scores for or I can see if there's an easier way, so ultimately thats my question, is there an easier way?

```
        scores_bool = {
            'spc': 1,
            'medical': 1,
            'photo_id': 1,
            'presolo_test': 1,
            'presolo_checkout': 1,
            'endorsement_solo': 1,
            'solo': 1,
            'dual_xc': 1,
            'inst_training': 1,
            'dual_night': 1,
            'tol_tower': 1,
            'solo_xc': 1,
            'solo_xc_150': 1,
            'checkride_prep': 1,
        }
        if ppl.spc:
            ppl.points += scores_bool['spc']
        if ppl.medical:
            ppl.points += scores_bool['medical']
        if ppl.photo_id:
            ppl.points += scores_bool['photo_id']
        if ppl.presolo_test:
            ppl.points += scores_bool['pre_solo_test']
```

So basically each ppl attribute has a True False statement, if true add the points to it...etc

Ideally I would loop through the scores_bool.keys() and say something like:

```
for i in scores_bool.keys():
if ppl.i: 
    ppl.points += scores_bool[i] 


Thankyou!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use built-in `getattr` method.

```
for i in scores_bool.keys():
    if getattr(ppl, i): 
       ppl.points += scores_bool[i]
```

For more information about how to call method by its string name, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string)

Comment: With this you have to be sure that the instance has every attribute from `scores_bool.keys()`, otherwise AttributeError will be raised. As far as this statement is just a predicate passing fallback value of `None` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close, but while `ppl.i` won't work, `getattr(ppl, i, None)` will.

```
for i in scores_bool.keys():
if getattr(ppl, i, None): 
    ppl.points += scores_bool[i]
```